# weird behaviour of lists of lists of variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, boolean

I'm creating for example a list of list variables. WHen I changed the one value, the whole column changed as well

```py
data = [[False] * 5] * 5
data
[[False, False, False, False, False],
 [False, False, False, False, False],
 [False, False, False, False, False],
 [False, False, False, False, False],
 [False, False, False, False, False]]

data[3][4] = True
data
[[False, False, False, False, True],
 [False, False, False, False, True],
 [False, False, False, False, True],
 [False, False, False, False, True],
 [False, False, False, False, True]]
```

Same happened if it is a numerical variable. why does this happen??

Answer (score -1):

oh i got it myself.....when i make data as = [] * 5, i am shallow copying them and thus change one changed all rows.

Comment: Marked a duplicate for you to get more info